# JUnit5 tests ignored with Maven and with Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit5

I am currently upgrading a project to use JUnit5.
I managed to import the necessary dependencies from jupiter and mockito extensions, to make all unit test (both Junit 4 and 5) with mocks run fine in IntelliJ.

At the moment my working solution has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

`mockito-core.version` = 3.0.0
`junit.version` = 5.2.0

**However** when i run tests via Maven, the JUnit5 tests are being ignored.

I saw on this blog: https://dev.to/martinbelev/how-to-enable-junit-5-in-new-spring-boot-project-29a8  that `spring-boot-starter-test` imports JUnit4, and therefore I have to exclude `junit` from this dependency. *However* `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency is being imported from a parent pom, so adding this exclusion:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

has no effect, the effective dependency `org.springframework.boot` is the one defined on the parent pom with an older version.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Thank you in advance!

Edit:

test class is:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SomeTest {

    private static final String TEST = "test";

    @Mock
    RetailerService retailerService;
    private Delivery delivery;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        when(retailerService.getMessage(any(String.class))).thenReturn(TEST);
        delivery = new Delivery(retailerService);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_have_delivery() {
        assertEquals(getExpectedDeliveriesDTOs(), delivery.toDtos());
    }

}
```

Comment: PS. I have no domain over the parent pom. So I cannot edit this dependency there :(

Comment: What is your `maven-surefire-plugin` version in pom.xml?

Comment: Hi Rozart, it is on my own project. I am using: `<version>2.22.2</version>` .

Comment: You have to import the bom of junit-jupiter (most recent version) before Spring boot. Second do not use vintage engine...and only use junit-jupiter-engine as dependency than no things needed to do for maven-surefire-plugin (best to use most recent version). Prevent usage of platform-surfire-provider!

Comment: If you import it via parent than you have to exclude the junit deps manually...

Comment: @khmarbaise That's why I have to use the bom i suppose then? I will try it. never done that before.

Comment: I managed to exclude the JUnit4 dependency from spring boot starter via dependencymanagement and also to import the JUnit bom for the lastest jupiter version. So the jars are updated correctly. However Junit5 tests are still ignored maybe because the surefire plugin version is also defined by parent and according to effective pom is set to 2.16 ...

Answer (score 0):

First - please verify if your test classes names:

1. Start or end with the string "Test"
2. End with string "Tests" or "TestCase"

If yes, then try the adding the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` and `junit-jupiter-engine` dependencies to the `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi @Rozart . Thanks for your reply. I do have Test in my test Classes names.
And also I have already tried importing those dependencies into the surefire-plugin.
But it did not change the outcome.

Comment: Could you please add some examples of your JUnit 5 tests and how exactly do you try to run them with maven?

Comment: I added the test class to the question. When I run the test via IntelliJ directly on the class it runs without errors. When I run either with mvn clean test or via IntelliJ's maven test all tests from JUnit4 run perfectly but JUnit5 test is ignored.